# New model in app do not create table in MySQL (Django)

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
Python: 3.4.4
Django: 1.9.3
Mezzanine: 4.1.0
```

I have created a new model in my apps models.py and when I run makemigrations and migrate it do not create a new table in the MySQL database.

**This is my model in `app/models.py`:**

```
from django.db import models
from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill

class FrontImage(models.Model):
        front_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads')
        front_image_thumb = ImageSpecField(source='front_image',
                                          processors=[ResizeToFill(780, 286)],
                                          format='JPEG',
                                          options={'quality': 70})
        class Meta:
            app_label = 'app'
```

**I've tried the following commands without any luck:**

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py migrate --fake
python manage.py migrate [app]
```

I saw in the django_migrations table that it recognized it, but I can't intepret it:

`47 app 0008_frontimage 2016-03-23 13:40:19`

Comment: Did you add your new app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: Try to supply more information. Does `makemigrations` work? Does it create any new migration `.py` file? If yes, what are the contents of that file?

Comment: Are you using any database routers?

Comment: You shouldn't have used `--fake` - it updates the migrations table in the db *without* running the migration. Can you show the ouput of `python manage.py showmigrations [app]`, and the contents of your `0008_frontimage` migration?

Comment: Why did you set `app_label = 'app'`? What is the app really called?